# Trouble connecting to SparkPost - Joomla 2.5.28 / Civicrm 4.6.14

Tags: civimail, ssl

I installed the SparkPost/CiviCRM extension and followed the README and all seems correct but I can not connect to SparkPost SMTP server.  Is anyone else seeing a problem?

[image: Error message]

Comment: I'd like to add that the above screenshot is without ssl:// -- If I use ssl:// with the smtp server name, the error message is:  Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.sparkpostmail.com:587 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: (code: -1, response: )]  I'm seeing this with my Drupal installs so it's not limited to Joomla...see comment below regarding successful send using external email client, no issue.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that you are trying to send an email with a "From address" that is not in the sending domain(s) that you have verified in SparkPost. I think they only allow email from verified domains, so you can't send "from" a Gmail address in CiviCRM, for example.

If you are having trouble with the PESC Sparkpost extension you may want to try the one from Cividesk. It only requires inputting the API code and is pretty much plug and play.

Comment: Thanks but I've confirmed that the from address is allowed.

Comment: See edits above for another suggestion.

Comment: The Cividesk extension worked on Drupal, will test on Joomla before posting answer, thanks @Laryn

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SparkPost specifically... however I use similar services with my CiviCRM installs...

Error seems to imply that your username and/or password is wrong: https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/questions/16067096-atomic-email-sender-errors?b_id=7411

### added in response to first comment

I ran into that on Google Compute Engine hosting. All mail ports but the non-standard 2525 were blocked. https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/articles/1988470-smtp-connection-problems

I would test the ports. ssh into the server and telnet the ports to see if you can talk to the mail server. You should get a response something like below (try 587 and 2525):

david@server ~ $ telnet smtp.sparkpostmail.com 587
Trying 54.191.237.37...
Connected to smtp.sparkpostmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 2.0.0 smtp.sparkpostmail.com ESMTP ecelerity 4.2.17.54068

Comment: I have validated my user/pass by using the credentials with my email client (Apple Mail).  No problems connecting to Sparkpost and sending email...no problem!  I would add that I'm seeing this issue with my Drupal installations as well...I'm wondering if there could be an issue with my hosting provider...

Comment: I ran into that on Google Compute Engine hosting. All mail ports but the non-standard 2525 were blocked. [link]https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/articles/1988470-smtp-connection-problems[/link]

I would test the ports. ssh into the server and telnet the ports to see if you can talk to the mail server. You should get a response something like below (try 587 and 2525):

david@server ~ $ telnet smtp.sparkpostmail.com 587
Trying 54.191.237.37...
Connected to smtp.sparkpostmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 2.0.0 smtp.sparkpostmail.com ESMTP ecelerity 4.2.17.54068